# How to send post value ajax using onclick a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to send post value ajax using onclick a tag ?

i create like this code but i not have any post value

how can i do that ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function reply_click(clicked_id){
        $('body').on('click','.like',function(){    
            var pro_id = $(this).attr('clicked_id');        
            var postData = 'pro_id='+pro_id;
            $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                url: "receiver.php",
                data: postData,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){            
                    $('#'+pro_id).html('OK').addClass('unlike').removeClass('like');
                }       
            });
        })
    });
</script>


<a class="like" onClick="reply_click(this.id)" style=" cursor: pointer; " id="99999999999999">click here.</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing it wrong, you are supposed to define document ready function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ....
```

and then you are not supposed to pass any value or give to html `onclick` attribute with any function call, since jQuery itself is enough to do this job for you. See my code below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click','.like',function(){    
            var pro_id = $(this).attr('id');        
            var postData = 'pro_id='+pro_id;
            $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                url: "receiver.php",
                data: postData,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){            
                    $('#'+pro_id).html('OK').addClass('unlike').removeClass('like');
                }       
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Your HTML can be like this

```
<a class="like" style="cursor: pointer;" id="99999999999999">Click here</a>
```